# Filling out empty cells with lists of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
         City         State              Country
      Chicago            IL        United States
       Boston                    
    San Diego            CA        United States
  Los Angeles            CA        United States
San Francisco
   Sacramento     
    Vancouver            BC               Canada
      Toronto
```

And I have 3 lists of values that are ready to fill in the None cells:

```
city = ['Boston', 'San Francisco', 'Sacramento', 'Toronto']
state = ['MA', 'CA', 'CA', 'ON']
country = ['United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'Canada']
```

The order of the elements in these list are correspondent to each other. Thus, the first items across all 3 lists match each other, and so forth. How can I fill out the empty cells and produce a result like below?

```
         City         State              Country
      Chicago            IL        United States
       Boston            MA        United States
    San Diego            CA        United States
  Los Angeles            CA        United States
San Francisco            CA        United States
   Sacramento            CA        United States
    Vancouver            BC               Canada
      Toronto            ON               Canada
```

My code gives me an error and I'm stuck.

```
if df.loc[df['City'] == 'Boston']:
    'State' = 'MA'
```

Any solution is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two mappings, one for `<city : state>`, and another for `<city : country>`.

```
city_map = dict(zip(city, state))
country_map = dict(zip(city, country))
```

Next, set `City` as the index -

```
df = df.set_index('City')
```

And, finally use `map`/`replace` to transform keys to values as appropriate -

```
df['State'] = df['City'].map(city_map)
df['Country'] = df['City'].map(country_map)
```

As an extra final step, you may call `df.reset_index()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I've got a question though. When I set `'City'` as the index, I got an error of `'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'`. I tried adding `inplace=True` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Karma I thought you said you had a DataFrame in your question, not a series?

Comment: Yes, the csv file should be a data frame

Comment: @Karma If `df` is a dataframe, then you shouldn't be getting the error you claim to have. What is `type(df)` printing?

Comment: Oh, it returns `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. You're right. Why is that?

Comment: @Karma I don't know, because I don't have your data or your code. Assuming `df` was a dataframe, this would work ;)

Comment: Oh, it seems that when I checked which cities were missing the states and countries with `df = df['City'][df['Country'].isnull()]`, it automatically changed the type from dataframe to series. So after I commented it out, it went back to dataframe. Now, my question is, the df['State'] and df['Country'] all went to blank (Nan).

Comment: No, I changed it back to dataframe `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` but all the states and countries went blank

Comment: @Karma Please produce a [mcve] with your issue, I don't see myself being able to solve your problem like this.

Comment: @Karma Now that I see the other answer, I realise it was a big typo in my answer. I profusely apologise, I've edited my answer accordingly, and it should definitely work. Once again, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Hey, not at all. Rather, I really appreciate your help. And even though it got me into scratching my head that head skin falls off (just exaggerated), I still learned a lot through your methods. Really no need to apologize.